# How Angular JS works when I defined ng-app in html tag?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Html parse from top to bottom.

But when I define ng-app into html tag and call it's library from script tag which is inside html tag.

So how AngularJS know that I have defined ng-app into html tag?

See below code for reference

```html
<html ng-app="myFirstApp">
 <head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
 </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Those are two different things. _Html parse from top to bottom._ True. AngularJS(wherever it is included), search for `ng-app` attribute on HTML from top to bottom. Before Angular do this, it is just another custom attribute. In AngularJS it has special meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Angular initializes automatically upon `DOMContentLoaded` event or when
>   the `angular.js` script is evaluated if at that time `document.readyState`
>   is set to `'complete'`. At this point Angular looks for the `ngApp`
>   directive which designates your application root. If the `ngApp`
>   directive is found then Angular will:
>
> - load the [module](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) associated with the directive.
> - create the application [injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector)
> - compile the DOM treating the `ngApp` directive as the root of
>     the compilation. This allows you to tell it to treat only a portion of
>     the DOM as an Angular application.

There are a lot of useful info in the official [developer guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide) docs, like this article about [bootstrapping](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap). Also you can walk through [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)